# Multiple database logs in backup device

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am working on tidying up our log back up Jobs (Sql 2008r2 ), which have grown into a bit of a mess!

I am setting up a trn log back up job to a remote folder for each day ( in this example  called Monday).
I  then plan to set a backup device to each folder with a filename of [DAYNAME]logs.trn eg Mondaylogs.trn

My plan is that the maintenance job will back up 5 production databases ( database A B C D E) log files every 15 minutes to the back up device file Mondaylogs.trn

The one thing I just want to confirm is, if I want to restore to a point in time on a Monday for  just one of the database  (let us say database B) I will be to achieve this from the single file Mondaylogs.trn?

If I am incorrect do I have to set up devices MondaylogsA.trn MondaylogsB.trn and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to restore a backup/log from a file which has more than 1 file inside, you can always select the file you want to restore for example

{RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.TRN' WITH NORECOVERY, FILE = 1
GO}[image]

Comment: Hi many thanks I thought so BUT  better safe than Sorry!